# Reduce duplicate sequences

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am writing a copy paste detector using [esprima.js](http://esprima.org/) and [Hmm](https://gist.github.com/konijn/2d2737b0f86792e27b32).

This particular function checks a number of sequences and reduces them.
Due to the parsing I might have 2 sequences with the same piece of text, if so I need to merge the 2 sequences and add the start/ends ( both are source token indexes ) and occurrences ( contains location of the dupes in the original source ).

Obviously I could apply some DRY to this code, but I feel that every time I start I actually make the code less readable. Also I am not too happy with the naming, is there some good vocabulary out there for comparing sequences what is a good name for `sequences[inner]` and `sequences[outer]`.

Anyway, all feedback is welcome, though I know that I am on a lonely crusade that `~` is so superior to `-1` that I am sticking it to it indefinitely.

```
  Tokens.prototype.reduceSequences = function()
  {  
    var sequences = this.sequences,
        tokens = this.raw();

    if( sequences.length < 2 )
      return;

    for( var outer = 1 ; outer < sequences.length ; outer++)
    {
      for( var inner = 0 ; inner < outer ; inner ++)
      {
        if( sequences[inner].content == sequences[outer].content )
        {

          if( !~sequences[inner].starts.indexOf( sequences[outer].starts[0] ) )
          {
            sequences[inner].starts.push( sequences[outer].starts[0] );
            sequences[inner].ends.push( sequences[outer].starts[0] + sequences[inner].tokenCount );            
            sequences[inner].occurences.push( sequences[outer].occurences[0] );
          }

          if( !~sequences[inner].starts.indexOf( sequences[outer].starts[1] ) )
          {
            sequences[inner].starts.push( sequences[outer].starts[1] );
            sequences[inner].ends.push( sequences[outer].starts[1] + sequences[inner].tokenCount );            
            sequences[inner].occurences.push( sequences[outer].occurences[1] );
          }          

          sequences.splice(outer, 1);         
          outer = 0;
          break;
        }        
        if( ~sequences[inner].content.indexOf( sequences[outer].content )  )
        {
          sequences.splice(outer, 1);       
          outer = 0;
          break;
        }        
      }  
    }
  }
```

A use case would be having 5 sequences ( sequences come in sorted by length )

```
[ 'I'm a sequence'(found on line 1&7) , 
  'I'm a sequence'(found on line 1&9) ,
  'I'm a sequence'(found on line 7&9) ,
  'I'm also a sequence'(found on line 2&3)
  'a sequence'(found on line 1&7) ,
  'a sequence'(found on line 1&9) ,
  'a sequence'(found on line 2&3) ,
]
```

The outcome would be

```
[ 'I'm a sequence'(found on line 1&7&9) ,   <-- Note how 9 got added
  'I'm also a sequence'(found on line 2&3)
   <- No more 'a sequence' , it is a substring of the first sequence
]
```

The algorithm starts taken sequence 1 till the end, and compares to all the prior sequences for dupes and larger sequences.

Comment: Please describe the desired algorithm in more detail and show before/after examples.

Comment: You won't have to stick to your `~` crusade indefinitely. In ES6 you can use `.contains`. :)

Comment: I kinda feel that `~` > `.contains()` > `indexOf()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use `reduce` to your advantage, and extracting a function to merge two sequences. (Edit: messed up 1st version; this should be better)

```
Tokens.prototype.reduceSequences = function () {
  // source and destination seem like slightly better names
  function merge(source, destination) {
    // can't merge, so return false
    if( !~destination.content.indexOf( source.content ) )
      return false;

    // no need to actually merge (source included in destination),
    // so just return true
    if( destination.content != source.content )
      return true;

    // otherwise, merge
    for( var i = 0, l = source.starts.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
      if( ~destination.starts.indexOf(source.starts[i]) ) continue;
      destination.starts.push( source.starts[i] );
      destination.ends.push( source.starts[i] + destination.tokenCount );
      destination.occurences.push( source.occurences[i] );
    }

    return true;
  }

  if(this.sequences.length < 2) return;

  this.sequences = this.sequences.reduce(function (sequences, current) {
    var merged, i, l;

    for( i = 0, l = sequences.length ; i < l && !merged ; i++ )
      merged = merge(current, sequences[i]);

    if( !merged )
      sequences.push(current);

    return sequences;
  }, []);
}
```

I think that should work.

Oh, and yes, I've undone your brace-on-new-line style - sorry, couldn't help myself. But I've left out braces I'd usually include, so I've met you halfway! :)

If `reduce` is not an option, I can't really come up with anything besides extracting a merge function (basically a "lighter" refactoring). Like so

```
Tokens.prototype.reduceSequences = function () {
  // source and destination seem like slightly better names to use *here*
  // but they don't make as much sense in the loops below, IMO
  function merge(source, destination) {
    for( var i = 0, l = source.starts.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
      if( ~destination.starts.indexOf(source.starts[i]) ) continue;
      destination.starts.push( source.starts[i] );
      destination.ends.push( source.starts[i] + destination.tokenCount );
      destination.occurences.push( source.occurences[i] );
    }
  }

  var sequences = this.sequences;

  for( var outer = 1 ; outer < sequences.length ; outer++) {
    for( var inner = 0 ; inner < outer ; inner ++) {
      if( sequences[inner].content == sequences[outer].content ) {
        merge(sequences[outer], sequences[inner]);
        sequences.splice(outer, 1);
        outer = 0;
        break;
      }

      if( ~sequences[inner].content.indexOf( sequences[outer].content )  ) {
        sequences.splice(outer, 1);
        outer = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's not brilliant, but either way it feels a tiny bit cleaner to encapsulate the "merge" step in a function.

By the way, `var tokens = this.raw()` didn't seem to be used for anything.

It might be more beneficial to simply add the `merge` function to your sequence objects, though. It'd clean up this particular code nicely. But you know better than I if something like that would make sense in your project.